# How to insert paranthesis,brackets,colon,double quotes inside column in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am working on application and i need to store `{ [ " : ] }` these characters inside column.

How can i do it?

Comment: What issue are you having?  Just put the values in a string and store them.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Please share more details, like the query you are using and the error message you are facing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of those character require special attention:

```
create table t (col text);
insert into t 
values ('{ [ " : ] }');
```

However, if you are planning to stor (valid) JSON values in that column, it's better to declare it as `jsonb` rather than text:

```
create table t (col jsonb);
insert into t 
values ('{"key1": 42, "key2": [1,2,3]}');
```

The only character that needs special attention in string literals in SQL is the single quote - which is escaped by [doubling it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS), e.g.: `'Arthur''s house'`